# Table type CSV dont created

Tags: mysql

I created a table type CSV but in PHPMyAdmin was created table with type MRG_MYISAM.

I read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/csv-storage-engine.html

> To enable the CSV storage engine if you build MySQL from source,
>   invoke configure with the --with-csv-storage-engine option.

Is it possible other methods to include this type ? Maybe my.ini ....

Comment: Not sure we have enough information to help, except to say that this is typically enabled by default, last I knew. Also, out of curiosity, why do you require this feature? Surely there's an alternative :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to know what storage engines are available you can run the following query:

```
show engines
```

The output will look like this:

```
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MyISAM     | YES     | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| InnoDB     | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| ARCHIVE    | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

As the documentation you've read explains, it's possible to decide on compilation time whether the MySQL binaries will include support for the CSV engine. If they don't, it's just not possible to use it. You cannot *enable* something that doesn't exist ;-)